# Separating Column number from Row letter in an Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to declare a range in an Excel formula and have the value returned by MATCH() as the row number?

Example:

`=VLOOKUP(C3,'Sheet2'!B2:C30000,2,FALSE)`

What I want is the formula equivalent of VBA's `"B" & [`*MATCH() return*`] & ":C30000"`.

I am not permitted to use VBA.

Comment: Use the indirect function

Answer (score 1):

Use Index, INDIRECT and OFFSET are volatile and should be avoided when possible.

```
=VLOOKUP(C3,INDEX('Sheet2'!B:B,MATCH(...)):'Sheet2'!C30000,2,FALSE)
```

Change the `MATCH(...)` to your Match formula.